# Can not remote debug JSP in Intellij 15 Ultimate Edition

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, intellij-idea, wso2-identity-server

I can remote debug JSP file in Eclipse with a remote java application (WSO2 Identity Server), but it did not work in Intellij 15 Ultimate Edition.

Added the following to the bat file.

`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8888,server=y,suspend=n`

The following configuration is done to Intellij

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Intellij 15 Ultimate Edition can debug without issue. It seems to be your .bat file command was incorrect. In CLI we used \>`wso2sever.bat -debug 8888`
I think you can used above command in .bat file like below.

```
full_path_to_Server_bin\wso2sever.bat -debug 8888
```

Above save in whatever.bat file and you can reused it.

Comment: Do I need to remove the -Xdebug from the bat file ?